# How to sort (non-standard) mysql data using iteration?

Tags: mysql

I have data columns:

```
id  name  type  number
 1   n1    t1    num1
 2   n2    t1    num2
 3   n3    t1    num3
 4   n10   t1    num10

 5   n4    t2    num4
 6   n5    t2    num5
 7   n6    t2    num6

 8   n7    t3    num7
 9   n8    t3    num8
 10  n9    t3    num9
```

Which select I shuld run to get this result?

```
id  name  type  number
 1   n1    t1    num1
 5   n4    t2    num4
 8   n7    t3    num7

 2   n2    t1    num2
 6   n5    t2    num5
 9   n8    t3    num8

 3   n3    t1    num3
 7   n6    t2    num6
 10  n9    t3    num9

 4   n10   t1    num10
```

I guess it could be right way to do it using procedure but is it possible to sort it in the simple query?

**Update1:**
name, type and number columns are independent. And I need to sort it by type as you can see in the result example.

Comment: And how are the tables linked ? No keys ?

Comment: I've selected all records and exported it to php array and did the group then. It is not right way.

Comment: @Cosmin, sure it has, updated post to understand it

Comment: This isn't grouping, this is sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  SELECT x.id,x.name,x.type,x.number
  FROM (SELECT t.id,
               t.name,t.type,t.number,
               CASE
                 WHEN @type != t.type THEN @rownum := 0
                 WHEN @type = t.type THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                 ELSE @rownum 
               END AS rank,
               @type := t.type
          FROM  scores t,
               (SELECT @rownum := 0, @type)var
      ORDER BY t.type)  x
ORDER BY x.rank, x.type
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2417a/2)

Comment: Yikes! That is exactly what I need! Thanks man!
Could you describe what does this string mean: (SELECT @rownum := 0, @type)var ?

Comment: That is to declare variable. You could read more here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html

Comment: @sel Can you clarify, what is `(SELECT @rownum := 0, @type)var` doing? I'm trying to figure it out but changing the sql to `(SELECT 0)var` yields  the same results - [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2417a/11)

Comment: It is to declare the variable and assign a default value to the variable. It still yields the same result in this query due to i did assign value here at  `WHEN @type != t.type THEN @rownum := 0` and `@type := t.type`.

Comment: why your script wouldn't work on some hosting? Mysql vesrsion both localhost and hosting has the same version. But localhost works correct, hosting - doesn't.

Comment: the data in both localhost and hosting is the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, type, number
from (
   select t1.name, t1.type, t1.number, count(*) as typeSubIndex
   from mytable t1
   join mytable t2 on t1.type = t2.type
   where t1.id >= t2.id
   group by t1.name, t1.type, t1.number
) order by typeSubIndex, type
```

Explanation:
- Joins your table with itself on the same type column, with an extra column called typeSubIndex that is the order of each type within its own group:

```
name type number typeSubIndex
n1   t1   num1   1
n2   t1   num2   2
n3   t1   num3   3
n10  t1   num10  4
n4   t2   num4   1
n5   t2   num5   2
n6   t2   num6   3
n7   t3   num7   1
n8   t3   num8   2
n9   t3   num9   3
```

Then it just sorts this result first by typeSubIndex, then by type.

Comment: If you have too much records this script takes lots of time to get result